# Exportar tabla a excel

Tags: php, sql, excel

contexto: los datos de la tabla que están en la imagen se obtiene de dos tablas separadas, son filtrados por una fecha inicial y una fecha final. Quiero lograr exportar exactamente la tabla que se genera, asi como el ejemplo de la imagen tendria que generar el archivo nada mas con esos 5 codigos, no brinda ningun error, si genera el archivo excel pero lo genera en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el archivo en donde muestra la tabla generada que se decea exportar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        
        <script> 
            (function($) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#listar_orden_tecnico").dataTable({
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "bLengthChange": true,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bScrollCollapse": true,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": true 
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);             
        </script> 
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >
    <form method="POST" action="formularios/excel.php">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="export"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Exportar a Excel</button>
            </form>
        <br>
        
        <table class="display"  border="1"  id="listar_orden_tecnico" 
                style=" background-color:  #DCDCDC; width: 70% ">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Codigo</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Descripcion</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Unidad</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. Entradas</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. Salidas</th>                    
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. hasta fecha</th>                    
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. total</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">fecha</th>  
                          
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody > 
             <tr > 
        <?php
        // put your code here
        require 'conexion.php';
        //session_start(); 
        
        $fecha_i = $_GET['fecha_i'];
        $fecha_f = $_GET['fecha_f'];
             
      
        $sql = "";
        $sql1 = "";
      
                 
        if ( $fecha_i && $fecha_f){
               

            
            
$sql5 =  "SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad, 
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas, 
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas, 
(SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos mo WHERe mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
                AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59' )) ) AS saldo, 
(SELECT m.cantidad FROM material AS m WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo ) AS total, mo.fecha 
from material as m 
inner join unidad_medida uni on uni.idunidad_medida = m.unidad 
inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
where mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
                AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY m.codigo ASC";

                            
        
           
             $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql5); 
             $i=  mysqli_num_rows($result);
             
             if(!empty($result) AND mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {    
                 
                        echo "<td style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".strtoupper($rows[0])."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[1]."</td>    
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[2]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[3]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[4]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[5]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[6]."</td>  
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[7]."</td>  </tr>";
                        }
                   }
                                     
                                        
                                           
           
            elseif ($i <= 0) {
                # code...
            
                echo "<td  style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>No se encontraron registros de acuerdo a la búsqueda</td> "
                . "<td style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>0</td> "
                        . "<td  style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>0</td> "
                        . "<td  style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>0</td> "
                     . "  </tr>";
            }                          
             
             
        }
       
        
             ?>                                
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="8">
                            
                            
                        </th> 
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

           


    </body>
</html>
```

Archivo excel.php, en este archivo esta el codigo que se utiliza para exportar la tabla a excel, al momento de precionar el boton de exportar si genera el archivo pero lo genera en blanco

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=documento_exportado_" . date('Y:m:d:m:s').".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");

    require_once 'conexion.php';
    
    $output = "";
    
    if(ISSET($_POST['exportar'])){
        $output .="
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Nombre/Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Unidad</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>
                        <th>entradas</th>
                        <th>salidas</th>
                        <th>saldo</th>
                        <th>Total. fecha</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                    </tr>
                <tbody>
        ";
        
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad, 
        (SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas, 
        (SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas, 
        (SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos mo WHERe mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
                        AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59' )) ) AS saldo, 
        (SELECT m.cantidad FROM material AS m WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo ) AS total, mo.fecha 
        from material as m 
        inner join unidad_medida uni on uni.idunidad_medida = m.unidad 
        inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
        where mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
                        AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY m.codigo ASC") or die(mysqli_errno());
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            
        $output .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$fetch['m.codigo']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['m.nombre_material']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['uni.unidad']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['entradas']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['salidas']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['saldo']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['total']."</td>
                        <td>".$fetch['mo.fecha']."</td>

                        

                    </tr>
        ";
        }
        
        $output .="
                </tbody>
                
            </table>
        ";
        
        echo $output;
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: Hola! Qué es `ISSET`?? Yo conozco [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Además, tu form no tiene ningún campo exportar. Eso seguro está dando false de alguna forma y nunca se evalúa lo que está dentro. Procura hacerle debug a tus $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION para resolver tus líos más rápido...

Comment: ya corregi lo del isset y tambien la correcion de cambiar "export" por "exportar".
Notice: Constant Servidor already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\manteniminetodeb\formularios\conexion.php on line 9
Notice: Constant Base_de_datos already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\manteniminetodeb\formularios\conexion.php on line 10
Notice: Constant Usuario already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\manteniminetodeb\formularios\conexion.php on line 11
Notice: Constant Contrasena already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\manteniminetodeb\formularios\conexion.php on line 14

ese es el archivo de conexion a la db